# I am finding it difficult to run python code on sublime text repl

Tags: python-2.7, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I am not able to run python code on sublime repl. But I am able to build the same python code without repl. Whenever I run the python code using sublime repl I am getting the error as "Invalid Syntax". I have attached the screenshot below for your reference.

[image: Python Sublime repl trouble]

Comment: Seems like the file you are trying to run/compile has the Python versions string for some reason. Can you please add the content of the your .py file?

Comment: Hi Dany. I reinstalled it and got it working :)..